# Object.assign vs assignment (=)

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I am trying to make an instance of an object. I got a little confused facing `Object.assign()`. What's the difference between the below 2 codes?

```
const obj3 = Object.assign(obj2, obj1);
```

and:

```
let obj2: model;
obj2= obj1;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assignment only creates another reference to the exact same object in memory. If you assign, then change by referencing one of the variable names, the other one will have changed too, since they're the same thing.

`Object.assign` will assign all enumerable own properties of the second (and further) parameters to the first parameter, and will return the first parameter. So

```
const obj3 = Object.assign(obj2, obj1);
```

is a bit like

```
for (const prop in obj1) {
  obj2[prop] = obj1[prop]
}
obj3 = obj2;
```

(with plain objects - skipping the own aspect)

They're quite different.

Comment: So Object.assign creates a new object and is not referenced to the old object, and if I try to change the object that Object.assign has created, the main object is not gonna change. Am I right?